# Covariance matrix and projection

Tags: linear-algebra, variance, covariance, projection

I have troubles understanding a geometrical meaning of a covariance matrix.

Let's say we have a data set containing two points (-1,1), (-1,2) and write them in to the matrix

$$D = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then we'll choose the unit-vector $v = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^T$.

And now, in [this article](http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/geometric-interpretation-covariance-matrix/) is the following statement:

> So, if we would like to represent the covariance matrix with a vector
>   and its magnitude, we should simply try to find the vector that points
>   into the direction of the largest spread of the data, and whose
>   magnitude equals the spread (variance) in this direction.
>
> If we define this vector as $v$, then the projection of our data $D$
>   onto this vector is obtained as $v^TD$, and the
>   variance of the projected data is $v^T\Sigma v$.

The covariance matrix $\Sigma$ looks like this:

$$
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Also, the projection of $D$ onto $v$ is the following vector:

$$
v^TD = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
\sqrt{2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, in our case

$$
v^T\Sigma v = \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right] \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{4}.
$$

So, could you, please, explain, how can $v^T\Sigma v$ be a variance of values projected on $v$? I would really appreciate "the proof", that $v^T\Sigma v$ equals variance, as I don't see, why it is true.

Comment: The variance is $v^T\Sigma{v}$ not $v^TDv$

Comment: @DavidM. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: Also, $v^TD\neq Dv$, as $D$ is not symmetric!

Comment: @DavidM. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry for the pedantic corrections. How did you compute the sample covariance matrix $\Sigma$? I calculate something rather different.

Comment: @DavidM. They weren't pedantic, but necessary :) Something like $\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$ ? I'm afraid I exchanged columns with rows before in hurry...

Comment: @DavidM. It works now! Still, I'm not sure why $v^TDv$ equals the variance of projected values... Could you, please, try to explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original data matrix containing the points (in this case, 2-dimension) is

$$ D = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} $$

A shift of origin can be performed to center the points (-1,1) and (-1,2).
The mean of the x coordinates = -1.
The mean of the y coordinates = 3/2.

This will transform the data matrix to

$$ D = \begin{bmatrix}
-1-(-1) & -1-(-1)\\
1-\frac{3}{2} & 2-\frac{3}{2}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

The covariance matrix is given by $DD^T$

$$ DD^T = \Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The projection (in this case, into 1-dimension) of the points in $D$ on a vector $v$ is given by $v^TD$.

$v^TD$ can now be thought of as your 'Projected Data Matrix (P)' whose components give the coordinates of the points in the projected space (in this case, along the vector $v$).

Noting that $DD^T=\Sigma$, the covariance (variance, if 1-dimension) of $P$ is thus given by $PP^T$,

$$PP^T=v^TD(v^TD)^T=v^TDD^Tv=v^T\Sigma v$$